# Dynamically Creating Elements at the Top and Bottom of Browser Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the following code to dynamically create an "overlay" `<div>` at the top and bottom of the browser window.

```
$(function() {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  $('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:' +
      winWidth + 'px;height:30px">TOP</div>');
  $('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:' +
      (winHeight - 30) + 'px;width:' + winWidth + 'px;height:30px">BTM</div>');
}
```

The top `<div>` appears exactly where I want it to.

But the bottom `<div>` is not visible. When inspect it in Google Chrome, it seems to indicate that it is below the bottom of the window.

Can anyone see what I've missed here?

**EDIT** My original code can be found at http://jsbin.com/uravif/41

Comment: Replace `top` property with `bottom: 0`.

Comment: Your code is working for me in jsfiddle...

Comment: Not working for me in Google Chrome. I'd take a look at your jsFiddle but you didn't include a link.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z9zv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're just missing in your CSS:

```
body{
  height:100%; /* to fix jsBin bug with $(window).height() */
}
```

otherwise play with the `bottom` position of your "BTM" :) element instead of `top` of course.

**edit**
`$(window).height()` will work great offline, so I just think you're messing with that jsBin bug

**[jsbin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/umedos/1/edit)**

Comment: Looks like the `bottom` property was what I needed. Although I still don't know why mine didn't work. What is this about setting the height of the body? How would that help? I'd prefer not to mess with any of the existing markup or styles.

Comment: @JonathanWood no, you don't need the `body height` if you're gonna use the bottom property! :) I was not sure what you're up to. `bottom` is your way to go definitely!

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But it might explain why my original code didn't work. As it stands, I have no idea how it would.

Comment: @JonathanWood it does not work cause it's positioned a bit OVER(!) the top element cause the body has no height!. By adding a `body{height:` jquery will understand the window height. (I'm not sure it's only an issue in jsBin, try offline) but `bottom` will push your element to the absolute bottom tho reaching the page bottom.

Comment: OVER(!) the top element? Sorry, but could you elaborate a bit further? My original code is at http://jsbin.com/uravif/41

Comment: I see. Sorry if I was messy with my explanation. the answer is simple: jsBin has the poor issue that it does not understants $(window).height() and it'll return `8` online, but if you download a demo and run locally than finally `$(window).height()` will work as supposed to work. http://jsbin.com/elebap/1/edit

Comment: @JonathanWood So yes. (not *over* sry for my EN) but ABOVE so 8px -30 = above the TOP element: http://jsbin.com/elebap/1/edit will return **8** online, but if you download will give you the right value! (jsBin bug :| , the only one I hope) so to fix that jsBin bug you have to add to CSS `body height:100%;`

Comment: Heh, well if it returned 8 at least it would be visible. For me, it was returning something like 3887px. Now that I check, this is way too big a number. Should be around 480px. So seems you are right about it being jsBin.

Comment: yes. Try to download your own demo and you'll be amazed :) had the same issue days ago, that's why I suggested you the body{height:N;}; $(window).height() should return the window height, not the document's one. So yes, 3000+ is waaaay too wrong! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but your code seems to be working for me (here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Z9zv/) ).

```
var winWidth = $(window).width();
var winHeight = $(window).height();
$('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:' +
      winWidth + 'px;height:30px">TOP</div>');
$('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:' +
      (winHeight - 30) + 'px;width:' + winWidth + 'px;height:30px">BTM</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a bottom style attribute that you can use for this:

```
$('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;bottom:30px;width:' + winWidth + 'px;height:30px">BOTTOM</div>');
```

The bottom attributes positions the element at xx px from the botton of screen.

Answer (score 1):

try below:

```
$(function() {
  var winWidth = $(window).width();
  var winHeight = $(window).height();
  $('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;top:0px;width:' +
      winWidth + 'px;height:30px">TOP</div>');
  $('body').append('<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:' + winWidth + 'px;height:30px">BTM</div>');
}
```

Comment: Do'h! That's way too easy!